# How to make "configurable directives"?

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, expression, directive

Say I have a directive element:

```
  <monkey-grid></monkey-grid>
```

Now, say I want to include some "options" so the monkey-grid.tpl.html renders in a specific fashion, and can be re-used in different circumstances.

```
  <monkey-grid tabbed></monkey-grid>
  <!-- also tried this -->
  <monkey-grid tabbed="true"></monkey-grid>
```

Then in my monkey-grid template, I'd like to do something like this, but it doesn't work even though I have transclude to set to false (so the original element remains). I'd like to have only the appropriate div visible.

```
  <div>

    <div ng-show="tabbed == true">TABS</div>
    <!-- also tried -->
    <div ng-show="vertical">VERTICAL</div>      

  </div>
```

is there some better way of making "configurable directives" for lack of a better term?

The directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('App.Directives').directive('monkeyGrid', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: false,
            controller: 'MonkeyController',
            templateUrl: 'main/app/components/mokneyGrid/mokney-grid.tpl.html'
        };
    });

}());
```

Comment: can you explain what goes wrong with  `<monkey-grid tabbed="true"></monkey-grid>` this approach ?

Comment: It seems it cannot access variable `tabbed`. I just tried setting `tabbed="1"` and testing `tabbed == 1` to eliminate type conversion problems-- no dice. TABS is still hidden.

Comment: can you show your full code ? will be better in fiddle

Comment: This is my full code, minus the actual directive which I'm adding now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to pass the attributes into scope:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('App.Directives').directive('monkeyGrid', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            vertical:'=vertical',
            tabbed:'=tabbed'
        },
        controller: 'MonkeyController',
        templateUrl: 'main/app/components/mokneyGrid/mokney-grid.tpl.html'
    };
});
```

}());

you can parse bound items like   using the `@` operator:

```
        scope: {
            fooey:'@fooey'
        },
```

This threw me off because normally in a template you can latch on to arbitrarily defined attributes. The reason you can't here is because they get lost during the angular compile phase, and you have to explicitly tell it to compile/bind them.

You can use even more brevity. The variable name becomes implicit:

```
        scope: {
            vertical:'=',
            tabbed:'='
        },
```